# Drop Down not working under Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have developed a drop down menu in CSS, but it doesn't seem to be working in Safari, yet works on every other browser, could anybody see an issue in the code?

It is using simple CSS that shoulden't be causing any issues

```
#nav {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}

ul#navigation {
}

ul#navigation li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

ul#navigation li a {
]}

ul#navigation li a:hover {

}

ul#navigation li:hover > a {
}

/* Drop-Down Navigation */
ul#navigation li:hover > ul
{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}

ul#navigation ul, ul#navigation ul li ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    visibility:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    width:180px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(64,119,149) 28%, rgb(64,119,149) 32%, rgb(83,153,186) 85%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(64,119,149) 28%, rgb(64,119,149) 32%, rgb(83,153,186) 85%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(64,119,149) 28%, rgb(64,119,149) 32%, rgb(83,153,186) 85%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(64,119,149) 28%, rgb(64,119,149) 32%, rgb(83,153,186) 85%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(64,119,149) 28%, rgb(64,119,149) 32%, rgb(83,153,186) 85%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.28, rgb(64,119,149)),
    color-stop(0.32, rgb(64,119,149)),
    color-stop(0.85, rgb(83,153,186))
);
    box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #ccc;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; 
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; 
    -o-transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; 
    transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear;     
}

ul#navigation ul {
    top: 43px;
    left: 1px;
}

ul#navigation ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 181px;
}

ul#navigation ul li {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    border:0 none;
}

ul#navigation ul li a {
    background:none;
    padding:7px 15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    border:0 none;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:150px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

ul#navigation ul li a:hover {
    background:none;
    padding:7px 15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    border:0 none;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:150px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

ul#navigation li a.first {
    border-left: 0 none;
}

ul#navigation li a.last {
    border-right: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: remove square bracket from ul#navigation li a

Comment: Submit your html & css in www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: You state the css shouldn't be causing the issue, but it is causing the issue: 1) You've got the declaration for the ul#navigation ul to be hidden AFTER the declaration to make it visible (so the hidden declaration overrides the visible declaration), so that's a problem.  2) You do not declare a top/left for the ul#navigation ul, 3) You'd probably be better off using the `left` property to show/hide the list than the `visiblity` property: To hide, `left: -999em;`, to show, `left: 0;`

Comment: @JacobClark Put your html here and we could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset the css before you do anything else: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/