# First drop down not working on Safari (WordPress)

Tags: html, wordpress, safari, html-select, dropdown

I'm looking for a solution to fix a non-working dropdown on Safari only. Somehow the first dropdown (Select Place) is not responding after a value has been selected. It is working fine on other browsers.

Link to page: *Deleted*

Can someone help me with this issue?

Related: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211597/drop-down-not-working-under-safari)

--- Update 26-05

I have updated all plugins and wordpress core files. Still no luck.

--- Update 31-05

Still no solution.

Comment: No one who can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It was a jQuery bug.
Please see here: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4363